# Background image in div not working (video included)

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have tried many forums and suggestions, only to fail for the past few days. 
My CSS works perfectly fine if I use firebug, or third party css live edits, but not working when page loads. The file paths are 100% correct, thus the reason it works live. I have included a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OL2TuYo3coU

I've tried background and background-image also.

I'd appreciate all the help you guys could muster. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sorry, here's the URL: [link](http://pixelperfectphotography.org/boston/boston.html)

Comment: your image's url not found. http://pixelperfectphotography.org/boston/css/photos/backgroundimage.jpg check if it correctly :)

Comment: The path is: [/boston/photos/backgroundimage.jpg](http://pixelperfectphotography.org/boston/photos/backgroundimage.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the image is missing from the path.

Replace this:

```
.firstpara {
    background-image: url('photos/backgroundimage.jpg');
}
```

With this:

```
.firstpara {
    background-image: url('../photos/backgroundimage.jpg');
}
```

Either Firebug or any browser built in Developer Tools have Console, if will help you to detect any errors on the web page.

Comment: Thank you!! You guys are amazing. I thought I've tried that a millions times! Nevertheless, I'm extremely overjoyed but this... I nearly gave up entirely.

Comment: .firstpara {
    background-image: url('../photos/backgroundimage.jpg');
}
worked perfectly fine